# IN statement in where clause returns data with same id

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subid IN (:key2) AND pricing=:rate2  AND Poscode=:postcode2  ORDER BY Poscode DESC LIMIT 60");
```

user keys in array of values only for subid, so I used `implode` and `IN` to select accordingly in the database.

Here's how I derive their values from user input:

```
$a=$data['sub'];//this is for subid

foreach($a as $v=>$k) 
  {

    $key[]=$v;

  }
 $key2=implode(',',$key);


$postcode=$data['postcode'];

$rate=$data['slider1'];
```

The problem is, since user keys in multiple subid, the query should search though the database for matching subid's, poscode as well as rate.

I suppose it should return, two records if two matching record found, one for the subid A and another for subid B.

But now, it returns two records but with same data,meaning same subid?

What made this query not return data with different id please?

Sample DATA

> A user registered for two posts.
>
> **Post 1: postA**
>
> **user name: userA**
>
> **subject: maths**
>
> rate: 50
>
> postcode:12345
>
> **Post 2: postB**
>
> **user name: userA**
>
> **subject: science**
>
> rate: 50
>
> postcode:12345

Now I want to perform search on this:

> I key in rate:50,
>
> postcode:12345
>
> subjects: maths, science
>
> Now I should get to see, two posts with two different IDs,subjects but
>   same user,postcode and rate.
>
> But What I see:
>
> Same id, same subject, same rate(which is
>   correct), same postcode(which is correct).

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, updated with sample